# Xam Grids with varying row size dependant upon data

Tags: xaml, grid

I am looking to do something with XAML so that the row heights within a grid are variable.   But I am not sure if it is possible.

I have two rows in a grid, and if there is data to fill each row then no issue.  But, if there is no data to fill the second row then I would like the data in the fist row to be in fact centered using both rows.

I can achieve this by using the Rowspan property, but can I make this dynamic, based upon whether there is data for the row or not?

If not is there any other way for me to achieve this?

Updated code follows.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" 
                       Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="{Binding DetailRowSpan}"  FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"
                       Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>

                </Grid>

            </StackPanel>
```

- thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Height property of the first row to *, and the height property of the second row to Auto:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

This will make the height of the second row 0 if there is nothing in it.  The first row will take up any available space.

EDIT: After re-reading your question and reading the comments, I think that what you are actually asking is how to dynamically make a single cell span multiple rows (or not), depending on whether the next grid has content for that column.  If that is the case, then I'd recommend creating a read-only integer property in the class that is bound to the cell whose height might vary.  The property should calculate the number of rows that the cell should cover by examining the adjacent rows.  It can then be bound to the RowSpan property of the grid.

Comment: great - thank you. What would I do if, when there was data for both rows, for the first row height to be bigger then  the second?

Comment: When you set a row's height to Auto, it will size to it's content.  when you set it's height to *, it will take up all of the available space, and resize it's content to fit that space.  WPF is all about relative sizing.  If you want to actually make the top row bigger, you would need to put something bigger into it.

Comment: WhenI use the code above it does not seem to behave exacltly how I want - irrespective of whether the second field (in row 1) is empty the first field stays in the same place.  Its is not centered if the second field is empty

Comment: Just an update here.. still trying this and it seems  that the VerticalAlignment="Center" that I am setting on the  Textbox,  will only apply within the Row that its being put in, even if the second row is empty.

Comment: Apologies, lost track of this one.  I see what you are trying to do here.  I'll post an edit.

Comment: No worries.  I have managed to get around it by binding the Rowspan property, so that when I know that I have nothing to put in the second row then I have set the RowSpan property to include that row as well.   I'll include the updated code above.  It only seems to work if I specify  exact sizes for the two rows.   Not sure if this is a good approach or not!  But it does give the effect that I am after.

Comment: Chris - thanks for that - I had done just that and got it working (As per my last comment) but have just seen your edit.  Pleased that is the same as what you suggested.  - Thanks!